# PHP: Is it possible to perform $_REQUEST on a variable's value

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am working on creating a customizable form where Admin Users can customize the questions that are asked. I have the page created: the questions appear on the page, adding a new question adds that question to the page, etc. However, I'm not sure how to process the variables into my MS SQL Server database.

The page's questions are populated as so:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
$count = 0;
$sel_query = "SELECT *
              FROM database.dbo.odr_actor
              ORDER BY odr_num ASC;";
$sel_result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sel_query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
while($sel_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sel_result)) {
?>
    <?php if($sel_row['col_type'] == 'varchar(255)'){ ?>
        <tr><td>
            <strong><?php echo $sel_row['col_ques']; ?> </strong>
            <input name="<?php echo $sel_row['colu_name']; ?>" />
        </td></tr>
    <?php }elseif($sel_row['col_type'] == 'varchar(256)'){ ?>
        <tr><td>
            <strong><?php echo $sel_row['col_ques']; ?></strong>
            <select name="<?php echo $sel_row['colu_name']; ?>" type="selectable" value="">
                <?php
                $col_col = $sel_row['colu_name'];
                $qry_count=1;
                $qry_query="Select * from database.dbo.sel_$col_col
                            ORDER BY sel_id ASC;";
                $qry_result = sqlsrv_query($con,$qry_query);
                while($qry_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry_result)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $qry_row["sel_value"]; ?>"><?php echo $qry_row["sel_value"]; ?></option>
                <?php $count++; } ?>
            </select>
        </td></tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php $count++; } ?>
```

The questions work fine. They display correctly, the selections are populated correctly, etc. But, I'm not sure how to add the values to the primary database.

```
$sel_query = "SELECT *
              FROM database.dbo.odr_actor
              ORDER BY odr_num ASC;";
$sel_result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sel_query) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
while($sel_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sel_result)) {
    $col_col2 = $sel_row['colu_name'];
    $col_col3 = $_REQUEST['$col_col2'];
    // Update Query 2
    $updat2="UPDATE database.dbo.tbl_actor SET
    $col_col2 = $col_col3
    where act_id='".$act_id."'";
    echo $updat2;
    sqlsrv_query($con, $updat2) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
$count++; }
```

Does anyone know how to put a variable into a request in PHP. For example: $_REQUEST['$col_col2'];?

If you want me to post any more of the code, just let me know

Cheers,

Comment: It’s not very clear what you’re asking or what you’re trying to do. The only code in your question that references `$_REQUEST` is `$col_col3 = $_REQUEST['$col_col2'];`. What are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: MySQL 5.7.8 introduced a native JSON data type that enables efficient access to data in JSON. This includes optimized storage, and automatic validation of JSON documents stored in JSON columns. Invalid JSON documents will produce an error.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does `$_REQUEST[$col_col2];` solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are accessing it on wrong way ...

```
$_REQUEST['$col_col2']
```

it's like the field name in the form is

```
name=$col_col2
```

because you access it in single quotes ''

try this - without **'...'**:

```
$_REQUEST[$col_col2]
```

Comment: This worked. Seems really easy. I had tried that before, but, I also had to change -- SET $col_col2 = $col_col3 -- to -- SET $col_col2 = '$col_col3'.